# How can m2mqtt subscribe two topic

Tags: c#, mqtt

I'm using  m2mqtt to get message ,but I can't individual subscribe two topic

I use ***client.Subscribe*** to Subscribe two topic,and use
***client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)***
to get message

But two topic's message is mixed together .
Is there any meth to divide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put an if statement into the message handler to branch based on the incoming messages topic `e.Topic`.

You can always write functions to handle the different message types and just call these from the message handler and pass the `MqttMsgPublishEventArgs` object to those functions.

Answer (score 1):

the client provides just one handler for receiving messages. You can find information about the topic in the MqttMsgPublishEventArgs (there is the Topic property for that). It doesn't make sense for a client having different handlers one for each topic you have subscribed to (maybe something impossible because you don't know how many topics the user subscribes upfront).